# why the spork not run?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, guard, spork

[Spork pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLM9O.png) 
 please help
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'spork'
    require 'rspec/core'

```
Spork.prefork do
end

Spork.each_run do
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|        
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|   
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
end
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the error message so that it can be read without clicking through and found by text search.

Comment: What are you turning into a slave..?

Answer (score 0):

Could be due to Rinda patching that doesn't work with newer Ruby versions on Windows: https://github.com/sporkrb/spork/pull/253

It's probably best to switch to something like Zeus or Spring, except that fork() doesn't work on Windows. So the best approach is to just use a virtual machine, like Vagrant to run the project on Linux. (Guard uses Listen, and Listen at 2.x supports TCP so you can edit files on the Windows machines and have Guard run the tests on the virtual machine).